# How to bind the selected value in selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf

Of five options in a selectOneMenu I chose the second option and persisted the entity.
On edit the persisted entity selectOneMenu always has the last option as its value.

For example,

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{userHome.user.leader}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{userHome.availableLeaders}" var="leader" itemLabel="#        {leader.name}" itemValue="#{leader}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

where availableLeaders is a list of users populated @PostConstruct method.

I am expecting the selectOneMenu to have the second option(chosen) on edit.

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = User.class, value = "userConverter")
public class UserConverter implements Converter {

    public UserConverter() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            String value) {
            EntityManagerFactory emf =     Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DefaultPersistenceUnit");
            EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
            Query q = em.createQuery("select query");
        return q.resultList().get(0);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) {
        return ((User) value).getName();
    }}
```

In User.java

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (this.getClass().isInstance(other)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public int hashCode() {
    HashCodeBuilder builder = new HashCodeBuilder();
    builder.append(getId());
    builder.append(getName());
    return builder.toHashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look here:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (this.getClass().isInstance(other)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Your `equals()` method is definitely broken. This returns `true` for **every** other `User` object, even though it internally holds a completely different user ID/name. So the selected item matches **every** available select item value. That's why you see the last item being preselected everytime.

Assuming that the `id` property is unique for every user, then the `equals()` method should at its simplest rather look like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (!(other instanceof User)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (other == this) {
        return true;
    }

    if (id != null) {
        return id.equals(((User) other).id);
    }

    return false;
}
```

which can also be summarized as follows

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return (other instanceof User) && (id != null) ? id.equals(((User) other).id) : (other == this);
}
```

Hint: a bit decent IDE like Eclipse can autogenerate `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) method.

#### See also:

- [Right way to implement equals contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181339/right-way-to-implement-equals-contract)
- [Generic reflective helper method for equals and hashCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417035/generic-reflective-helper-method-for-equals-and-hashcode/4417048#4417048)

Comment: A missing equals method might also give similar symptoms (e.g. a wrongly selected item)

Comment: @dvtoever: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069379/validation-error-value-is-not-valid/9069660#9069660